# How can I implement many to many relation between to table in Laravel using join?

Tags: sql, laravel, join, relationship

I want to create relation between to entity in Laravel but without using eloquent many to many model relation, so I guess I should use join. am I right?
can I do this by using join? if I right, then how can do this?

I try to relate to entity but I do not want to use model relations.